# How to color scatter plot points based on temporal sequence

Tags: r, colors

I have a dataframe with observations of a temporal event. I can easily plot the observations based on their `X`and `Y` values, either in `base R` or `ggplot2`:

```
plot(df$Y ~ df$X)

ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]
What I'd like to do though is add in the temporal dimension by coloring the observations differently depending on the time they were made. This could be done by defining thresholds for different time steps and assigning discrete colors to each time step. But what I'm interested in is a **continuous coloring** where the flow of time can be directly read off the flow of colors or color hues or color transparencies. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Reproducible data** (slightly shorter than data underlying shown graphs):

```
structure(list(X = c(171.000358830368, 171.453956550099, 171.075127685269, 
171.140924277581, 171.271520544141, 171.582558980529, 171.23762532992, 
171.70218914837, 171.318375693213, 170.939546828382, 171.70218914837, 
171.779948757467, 171.809856299427, 172.066064242221, 171.603494259901, 
171.718139837416, 171.947430992445, 171.930483385334, 172.002261486039, 
172.153793031971, 122.654817251517, 171.710164492893, 172.012230666692, 
171.395138384244, 171.750041215507, 171.631407965731, 171.927492631138, 
172.059085815763, 171.816834725885, 170.787018364384, 170.328436054326, 
170.083194210252, 170.405198745358, 170.505887469957, 170.429124778926, 
171.187779426653, 171.00634033876, 170.984408141322, 170.731190952725, 
170.924593057402, 170.570687144205, 170.751129314032, 170.539782684179, 
170.561714881617, 170.461026157017, 170.631499146191, 170.686329639785, 
170.863781055416, 170.782033774058, 170.655425179759, 170.645455999106, 
170.612557702949, 170.658415933955, 170.514859732545, 170.382269629855, 
170.167932245806, 170.187870607113, 169.841940038438, 175.365863038509, 
190.973612269532, 206.626222813496, 214.924568789419, 214.509850874236, 
211.538038121446, 209.610995501136, 207.007045514458, 204.585531533737, 
202.489012842319, 200.693563406635, 199.331773329375, 198.61997383072, 
198.494362154486, 202.238786407918, 205.8695620019, 206.616253632843, 
207.53541208909, 208.81146721273, 209.850255836818, 210.903998231887, 
211.630751501523, 211.825150524265, 211.487195300113, 210.759445112412, 
209.407624215806, 207.816542983517, 205.843642132201, 203.585622714198, 
201.110275157949, 198.862224920598, 196.914247020916, 195.676074783759, 
195.283289066014, 196.015026925976, 197.60710507633, 200.479226022586, 
204.110001616568, 207.405812740595, 210.878078362188, 214.015379513825, 
216.768867210305, 218.423751198776, 219.404718575074, 219.467524413191, 
218.760709504862, 217.317172146244, 215.572565531892, 213.46408382369, 
211.338654508377, 209.181323814973, 207.720838849244, 206.537497105681, 
205.904454134187, 205.898472625795, 205.953303119389, 206.365030280376, 
206.977137972497, 208.319986606516, 209.067675155523, 209.547192744954, 
210.106463779612, 210.356690214013, 210.602928976153, 210.692651602034, 
210.849167738293, 210.88405987058, 210.998705448095, 211.037585252643, 
210.902004395756, 210.895025969299, 210.958828725481, 210.92692734739, 
210.975776332592, 211.201079815359, 211.164193846942, 211.304759294155, 
210.646793371028, 198.816366689593, 179.579835700717, 164.568243472769, 
159.956500502489, 159.636489803513, 159.535801078913, 159.997374143168, 
160.238628314981, 160.281495791791, 160.576583539133, 160.637395541118, 
156.724492134644, 153.810500629644, 153.846389679996, 154.022844177562, 
154.29300897327, 154.442546683072, 154.536256981214, 154.665856329709, 
154.665856329709, 154.833338564686, 156.847113056681, 176.676810294436, 
177.112463488991, 176.71868085318, 176.042770404877, 175.822451512436, 
175.75964567432, 176.817375741649, 176.028813551962, 176.347827332872, 
176.622976718907, 182.215687065486, 118.910392998086, 174.380907989949, 
171.889609744655, 168.855988071813, 164.924143222097, 160.275514283399, 
156.671655477181, 154.165403460906, 107.676123319726, 107.769833617868, 
108.581324923058, 109.676937876871, 109.244275436511, 110.393721965853, 
161.248506315174, 163.97707106002, 165.507340290323, 166.298893234206, 
168.008607716271, 169.06434394747, 170.018394536004, 170.41118025375, 
170.202824378093, 170.201827460028, 121.025853132745, 117.483803246579, 
120.870333914552, 166.984772863163, 166.489304584687, 168.118268703459, 
181.382263562859, 196.653054487796, 135.095357788943, 135.297732156208, 
202.44614536551, 203.460011037964, 204.440978414263, 205.227546767819, 
205.43490572541, 204.935449774673, 203.891676560258, 202.264706277617, 
199.827241607851, 176.081650209426, 194.729002621683, 194.670184455827, 
191.186952735516, 190.463190220076, 190.508051533017, 191.482040482858, 
186.606114225261, 171.208714706025, 158.889798172571, 149.82880987666, 
152.986049389604, 156.597883540345, 159.647455902232, 161.754940692369, 
162.893421122992, 114.542894953814, 162.976165322415, 114.268742485845, 
160.762010299286, 159.259654774813, 157.995562667957, 156.561994489993, 
155.638848361484, 154.469463470836, 154.00390273432, 154.431580584353, 
154.255126086787, 155.244068807608, 157.058459686534, 159.101144802424, 
161.906472238301, 165.29399982434, 120.406767014167, 172.028181355737, 
175.03588315888, 177.740521870158, 179.910812498411, 181.483949205524, 
181.988389746588, 181.854802725832, 180.508963337618, 178.901931416283, 
176.58609075049, 173.537515306668, 170.679351213327, 167.374567826712, 
164.487493109477, 162.203553821774, 160.569605112675, 159.562717866678, 
159.828894990125, 159.632502131252, 160.2495944137, 161.450880682439, 
162.705003608642, 164.622077048298, 166.212161362521, 167.468278124855, 
168.602770883216, 169.155063491416, 169.462114255542, 169.404293007752, 
169.003531945484, 168.422328713389, 167.728473739909, 166.825265972708, 
165.984864043623, 169.386348482576, 183.504702123976, 200.99862033463, 
214.553715269111, 218.552353629205, 217.590327696148, 217.000152201465, 
216.115885877505, 215.405083296914, 214.675339273083, 214.063231580962, 
213.56477254829, 212.972603217475, 212.488101037718, 212.097309156103, 
211.685581995116, 211.786270719716, 211.46426618461, 210.97178866033, 
210.657759469747, 210.36167480434, 210.032691842776, 209.635918452769, 
209.435537921635, 209.197274504018, 209.046739876151, 208.712772324261, 
208.585166811897, 208.3319496233, 203.956476234505, 189.73444311431, 
179.21097601654, 176.815381905519, 177.826256823777, 175.90718954799, 
175.461567172782, 177.582011897768, 177.488301599626, 177.463378647992, 
177.577027307441, 177.676719113976, 177.633851637166, 177.843204430888, 
177.995732894886, 177.92196095805, 176.699739409939, 176.824354168107, 
176.859246300394, 176.68877331122, 175.325986315895, 176.695751737677, 
174.103764767783, 176.520294158177, 178.304777495142, 176.684785638959, 
176.697745573808, 177.861148956064, 176.614004456319, 176.121526932039, 
176.364774939983, 173.25239673998, 176.064702602315, 174.207444246579, 
174.133672309744, 173.831606135945, 174.066878799366, 174.03597433934, 
175.830426856959, 174.100774013587, 174.019026732229, 173.965193156701, 
173.955223976047, 174.028995912883, 173.886436629538, 174.420784712563, 
179.872929611928, 198.741597834692, 208.031877285631, 208.418681494985, 
208.232257816765, 247.112062365176, 207.772678588642, 207.722832685375, 
207.639091567886, 207.613171698187, 207.569307303312, 207.722832685375, 
207.850438197739, 208.002966661736, 208.157488961865, 208.43463218403, 
208.722741504914, 209.112536468464, 209.628940026312, 210.13038981318, 
211.046557515231, 211.660659043483, 212.448224315105, 213.349438246175, 
212.024534137333, 215.36321273817, 216.563502088844, 217.81264042472, 
217.271313915238, 218.686937568026, 220.266055783531, 221.81426953901, 
223.14814591044, 224.246749618449, 225.106092990776, 225.724182191289, 
226.127934007753, 226.088057285139, 225.885682917874, 225.557696874376, 
225.048271742986, 257.697338382997, 223.992535511786, 223.464168937154, 
223.130201385264, 222.831125965661), Y = c(150.561649721083, 
150.067708443465, 150.155166858818, 149.178216605502, 149.407794945803, 
148.660423032789, 148.913853668186, 148.276798619991, 148.487493893341, 
147.692417390134, 148.3284785927, 147.692417390134, 147.963737246853, 
147.216365333839, 147.264069924031, 145.992941364529, 145.626212327424, 
144.316323788391, 144.345145311632, 143.45465962804, 118.779460351005, 
143.071035215242, 143.299619709914, 142.858352250634, 142.574112400738, 
141.615051368744, 141.139993158078, 140.643070343573, 140.190870582374, 
140.33597204421, 140.341935117984, 139.946384557638, 140.207765958067, 
139.045960417756, 139.269575684283, 138.122677828407, 138.177339338002, 
137.268964433088, 137.874216421154, 137.406115129891, 138.076960929472, 
137.840425669768, 138.343311558047, 137.691348825417, 138.413874597706, 
137.837444132881, 138.70109598449, 138.061059399408, 138.395985376384, 
137.616810403241, 138.267779290242, 137.52736429663, 138.054102480005, 
137.291822882555, 137.941797923927, 137.242130601105, 137.811604146527, 
137.343502855264, 137.326607479571, 135.242513195539, 137.238155218589, 
138.312502343547, 139.236778778526, 138.86110513076, 139.273551066799, 
138.584816045896, 138.903840492808, 137.509475075308, 137.144733729462, 
135.697694493625, 135.567500716225, 134.488184363121, 135.142134787009, 
134.959267191271, 135.420411563131, 134.819134957581, 135.649989903432, 
135.13120248509, 136.041565081262, 135.646014520916, 136.444072561011, 
135.969014350344, 136.521592520073, 135.799066747784, 136.416244883398, 
135.748380620704, 136.195611153758, 135.349848523472, 135.534703810467, 
134.372898270156, 134.413645940945, 133.470486439016, 133.743793986993, 
133.129597388266, 133.61658174648, 133.007354375898, 133.341286507245, 
132.799640639435, 133.348243426648, 132.845357538369, 133.241901944344, 
132.396139314057, 132.584969983569, 131.617958186543, 131.839585761812, 
130.896426259883, 130.981896983977, 129.944322147292, 129.993020583113, 
128.968365739605, 128.960414974573, 127.798609434262, 128.082849284158, 
127.096954420181, 127.450763464109, 126.738176148109, 127.149628238519, 
126.326724057699, 127.023409843635, 126.595062377532, 127.240068190759, 
126.893216066235, 127.574000322106, 127.072108279456, 127.73997254215, 
127.304668156644, 128.098750814222, 127.663446428716, 128.521135206551, 
128.014273935757, 128.852085801011, 128.420756798021, 129.41460242703, 
128.987248806556, 129.867796033858, 129.49510392298, 129.345033233, 
128.14148617627, 130.371675767766, 130.815924763933, 131.900210345182, 
131.529505925561, 132.387194703396, 131.814739621087, 132.715163760969, 
132.186437886336, 133.071954341783, 132.563105379731, 133.595710988271, 
133.373089567373, 134.173135298725, 133.956476951601, 134.797270353743, 
134.562722785297, 135.403516187438, 135.163005545218, 135.992866645441, 
131.572241287609, 129.463300862852, 122.968519677278, 123.474387102444, 
123.527060920781, 124.246605156184, 123.732786965986, 117.399008772312, 
123.862980743386, 124.421521986889, 123.70893467089, 124.808127936574, 
126.778923818898, 124.377792779213, 122.935722771521, 124.517925012903, 
124.076657553623, 124.838937151073, 124.239648236781, 124.81210331909, 
125.153986215469, 125.120195464083, 123.901740722918, 123.046039636341, 
120.966914580454, 120.263271875116, 121.53241274336, 121.521480441441, 
120.071459668717, 121.39228050967, 120.229481123729, 120.093324272555, 
118.693989626911, 118.729768069555, 117.589827133082, 118.195079121148, 
108.618382640018, 113.465367772695, 107.992259893742, 117.911833116881, 
117.31055651133, 118.451491293432, 122.158535489636, 128.127572337464, 
125.310019979223, 125.468041434236, 128.644372064548, 129.146264107198, 
128.288575329363, 128.90376577372, 128.18124000143, 128.778541224465, 
128.358144523394, 129.135331805279, 128.537036736615, 128.94351959888, 
128.079867747271, 127.956630889274, 126.952846803975, 126.741157684996, 
125.517733715686, 125.563450614621, 124.14026367388, 123.462460954896, 
122.454701487081, 125.26330923466, 123.721854664067, 123.747694650421, 
122.82639975233, 123.206048782611, 122.267858508827, 115.131053046914, 
122.130707812024, 114.510893374412, 122.343390776632, 123.249777990288, 
122.697199820559, 123.432645586025, 123.527060920781, 123.925593018014, 
123.003304274293, 124.011063742109, 123.917642252982, 125.041681659391, 
124.907512499475, 125.786072035519, 125.602210594152, 126.27603793062, 
114.507911837525, 126.00571191953, 125.382570710141, 125.88446275279, 
125.144047759179, 125.545561393298, 124.766386420155, 124.993977069198, 
124.193931337846, 124.197906720362, 123.290525661077, 123.403824062784, 
122.544147593691, 122.783664390282, 121.98361865893, 122.607753713948, 
122.271833891343, 122.822424369814, 122.699187511817, 122.789627464057, 
122.228104683666, 122.501412231644, 121.437997408604, 121.568191186005, 
120.996729949324, 121.368428214574, 120.744293159556, 121.303828248688, 
120.7800716022, 121.339606691332, 120.856597715634, 121.619871158713, 
121.218357524593, 121.974674048269, 121.564215803488, 122.684279827382, 
121.975667893898, 124.308223585182, 126.514560881582, 128.363113751539, 
128.091793894819, 128.702015111031, 128.509209059003, 129.155208717859, 
128.840159653463, 129.56566696264, 129.235710213809, 130.013891341323, 
129.748534558377, 130.711570972887, 130.380620378427, 129.980100589936, 
129.586537720849, 130.563487974165, 130.419380357958, 131.614976649656, 
131.552364375028, 132.790696028774, 132.718145297856, 133.984304629213, 
134.010144615568, 135.165987082105, 135.426374636905, 136.790924685535, 
135.130208639461, 129.957242140469, 126.592080840645, 127.358335820611, 
127.887061695243, 129.049861081184, 128.986254960927, 130.73840480487, 
130.834807830884, 132.108917927273, 132.045311807017, 133.056052811719, 
132.901012893594, 133.848147778039, 133.514215646692, 134.505079738814, 
134.604464301715, 135.360780825391, 135.037780995963, 135.768257533284, 
134.735651924744, 135.809999049703, 134.344076746915, 135.788134445865, 
127.311625076047, 135.801054439042, 135.322020845859, 127.889049386501, 
135.320033154601, 135.615205306417, 126.665625417191, 134.175122989983, 
126.25616101804, 134.430541316638, 133.848147778039, 134.240716801498, 
133.809387798508, 134.271526015997, 126.20547489096, 134.244692184014, 
133.780566275267, 134.294384465464, 133.818332409169, 134.256618331562, 
133.891876985716, 134.534895107684, 127.426911169012, 142.477709374724, 
146.033689035318, 147.092134630213, 146.619064110804, 170.36998695286, 
146.552476453661, 147.216365333839, 146.709504063044, 147.474765197381, 
147.046417731278, 147.842488080114, 147.290903756014, 148.023367984594, 
147.353516030642, 147.901124972226, 147.171642280533, 147.729189678407, 
147.072257717632, 147.535389780751, 147.15474690484, 146.832740921041, 
146.568377983725, 146.13207975259, 144.739702026348, 145.216747928273, 
144.640317463447, 144.137431575169, 143.147561328676, 141.941032735059, 
141.073405500934, 140.496975036109, 140.057695268087, 139.778424646336, 
139.654193942709, 139.203981872768, 138.923717405388, 138.393997685126, 
137.79868415335, 137.209333695347, 136.706447807069, 165.401752653445, 
135.932242062071, 135.629119145223, 135.168968618992, 134.679002723891
), starttime_ms = c(310849, 310865, 310882, 310899, 310915, 310932, 
310949, 310965, 310982, 310999, 311015, 311032, 311049, 311065, 
311082, 311099, 311115, 311132, 311149, 311165, 311182, 311199, 
311215, 311232, 311249, 311265, 311282, 311299, 311315, 311332, 
311349, 311365, 311382, 311399, 311415, 311432, 311449, 311465, 
311482, 311499, 311515, 311532, 311549, 311565, 311582, 311599, 
311615, 311632, 311649, 311665, 311682, 311699, 311715, 311732, 
311749, 311765, 311782, 311799, 311815, 311832, 311849, 311865, 
311882, 311899, 311915, 311932, 311949, 311965, 311982, 311999, 
312015, 312032, 312049, 312065, 312082, 312099, 312115, 312132, 
312149, 312165, 312182, 312199, 312215, 312232, 312249, 312265, 
312282, 312299, 312315, 312332, 312349, 312365, 312382, 312399, 
312415, 312432, 312449, 312465, 312482, 312499, 312515, 312532, 
312549, 312565, 312582, 312599, 312615, 312632, 312649, 312665, 
312682, 312699, 312715, 312732, 312749, 312765, 312782, 312799, 
312815, 312832, 312849, 312865, 312882, 312899, 312915, 312932, 
312949, 312965, 312982, 312999, 313015, 313032, 313049, 313065, 
313082, 313099, 313115, 313132, 313149, 313165, 313182, 313199, 
313215, 313232, 313249, 313265, 313282, 313299, 313315, 313332, 
313349, 313365, 313382, 313399, 313415, 313432, 313449, 313465, 
313603, 313619, 313636, 313665, 313682, 313699, 313715, 313732, 
313749, 313765, 313782, 313799, 313815, 313832, 313849, 313865, 
313882, 313899, 313915, 313932, 313949, 313965, 313982, 313999, 
314015, 314032, 314049, 314065, 314082, 314099, 314115, 314132, 
314149, 314165, 314182, 314199, 314215, 314232, 314249, 314265, 
314282, 314299, 314315, 314332, 314349, 314365, 314382, 314399, 
314415, 314432, 314449, 314465, 314482, 314499, 314515, 314532, 
314549, 314565, 314582, 314599, 314615, 314632, 314649, 314665, 
314682, 314699, 314715, 314732, 314749, 314765, 314782, 314799, 
314815, 314832, 314849, 314865, 314882, 314899, 314915, 314932, 
314949, 314965, 314982, 314999, 315015, 315032, 315049, 315065, 
315082, 315099, 315115, 315132, 315149, 315165, 315182, 315199, 
315215, 315232, 315249, 315265, 315282, 315299, 315315, 315332, 
315349, 315365, 315382, 315399, 315415, 315432, 315449, 315465, 
315482, 315499, 315515, 315532, 315549, 315565, 315582, 315599, 
315615, 315632, 315649, 315665, 315682, 315699, 315715, 315732, 
315749, 315765, 315782, 315799, 315815, 315832, 315849, 315865, 
315882, 315899, 315915, 315932, 315949, 315965, 315982, 315999, 
316015, 316032, 316049, 316065, 316082, 316099, 316115, 316132, 
316149, 316165, 316182, 316199, 316215, 316232, 316249, 316265, 
316282, 316299, 316315, 316332, 316349, 316365, 316382, 316399, 
316415, 316432, 316449, 316465, 316482, 316499, 316515, 316532, 
316549, 316565, 316582, 316599, 316615, 316632, 316649, 316665, 
316682, 316699, 316715, 316732, 316749, 316765, 316782, 316799, 
316815, 316832, 316849, 316865, 316882, 316899, 316915, 316932, 
316949, 316965, 316982, 316999, 317015, 317032, 317049, 317065, 
317082, 317099, 317115, 317132, 317149, 317165, 317182, 317199, 
317215, 317236, 317253, 317269, 317286, 317303, 317319, 317336, 
317353, 317369, 317386, 317403, 317419, 317436, 317453, 317469, 
317486, 317503, 317519, 317536, 317553, 317569, 317586, 317603, 
317619, 317636, 317653)), row.names = c(123318L, 123324L, 123333L, 
123343L, 123354L, 123363L, 123370L, 123373L, 123376L, 123384L, 
123391L, 123399L, 123406L, 123414L, 123424L, 123434L, 123438L, 
123440L, 123444L, 123446L, 123449L, 123459L, 123468L, 123477L, 
123483L, 123491L, 123502L, 123505L, 123509L, 123516L, 123523L, 
123526L, 123532L, 123538L, 123548L, 123556L, 123565L, 123570L, 
123574L, 123576L, 123580L, 123586L, 123593L, 123602L, 123611L, 
123617L, 123623L, 123627L, 123631L, 123640L, 123648L, 123652L, 
123663L, 123671L, 123674L, 123677L, 123684L, 123691L, 123696L, 
123706L, 123714L, 123725L, 123733L, 123735L, 123739L, 123741L, 
123745L, 123751L, 123756L, 123766L, 123775L, 123777L, 123786L, 
123794L, 123800L, 123807L, 123813L, 123816L, 123819L, 123823L, 
123833L, 123842L, 123850L, 123861L, 123869L, 123876L, 123884L, 
123892L, 123897L, 123904L, 123910L, 123912L, 123917L, 123926L, 
123933L, 123939L, 123945L, 123949L, 123953L, 123956L, 123962L, 
123968L, 123975L, 123981L, 123988L, 123996L, 124005L, 124015L, 
124020L, 124023L, 124029L, 124036L, 124045L, 124054L, 124063L, 
124069L, 124079L, 124085L, 124094L, 124103L, 124112L, 124117L, 
124124L, 124127L, 124130L, 124137L, 124146L, 124158L, 124169L, 
124177L, 124184L, 124189L, 124195L, 124203L, 124213L, 124220L, 
124227L, 124234L, 124244L, 124252L, 124257L, 124259L, 124262L, 
124265L, 124271L, 124279L, 124291L, 124299L, 124304L, 124312L, 
124321L, 124324L, 124328L, 124337L, 124343L, 124347L, 124354L, 
124363L, 124415L, 124424L, 124426L, 124435L, 124440L, 124446L, 
124454L, 124461L, 124467L, 124469L, 124476L, 124486L, 124493L, 
124496L, 124504L, 124510L, 124519L, 124524L, 124531L, 124539L, 
124550L, 124555L, 124558L, 124560L, 124564L, 124569L, 124579L, 
124586L, 124595L, 124599L, 124608L, 124617L, 124622L, 124629L, 
124634L, 124636L, 124640L, 124645L, 124653L, 124660L, 124669L, 
124681L, 124694L, 124700L, 124709L, 124716L, 124722L, 124727L, 
124730L, 124733L, 124738L, 124743L, 124748L, 124755L, 124766L, 
124774L, 124782L, 124786L, 124793L, 124801L, 124808L, 124812L, 
124821L, 124831L, 124844L, 124852L, 124861L, 124867L, 124873L, 
124877L, 124883L, 124890L, 124901L, 124912L, 124917L, 124921L, 
124926L, 124934L, 124943L, 124948L, 124956L, 124958L, 124962L, 
124968L, 124977L, 124986L, 124995L, 125005L, 125013L, 125015L, 
125018L, 125025L, 125036L, 125046L, 125051L, 125056L, 125063L, 
125072L, 125076L, 125078L, 125082L, 125084L, 125091L, 125100L, 
125111L, 125118L, 125128L, 125135L, 125143L, 125147L, 125155L, 
125165L, 125168L, 125170L, 125178L, 125188L, 125195L, 125203L, 
125212L, 125217L, 125220L, 125222L, 125226L, 125238L, 125245L, 
125252L, 125256L, 125262L, 125269L, 125278L, 125285L, 125288L, 
125292L, 125296L, 125307L, 125319L, 125322L, 125325L, 125329L, 
125334L, 125342L, 125351L, 125360L, 125372L, 125379L, 125386L, 
125389L, 125392L, 125397L, 125402L, 125411L, 125421L, 125428L, 
125436L, 125446L, 125451L, 125457L, 125459L, 125465L, 125470L, 
125477L, 125483L, 125490L, 125499L, 125508L, 125515L, 125523L, 
125526L, 125532L, 125540L, 125548L, 125550L, 125553L, 125558L, 
125564L, 125570L, 125580L, 125588L, 125594L, 125600L, 125604L, 
125610L, 125617L, 125624L, 125633L, 125640L, 125647L, 125655L, 
125661L, 125669L, 125676L, 125679L, 125686L, 125695L, 125706L, 
125716L, 125725L, 125733L, 125737L, 125743L, 125755L, 125758L, 
125762L, 125764L, 125769L, 125775L, 125783L, 125790L, 125800L, 
125808L, 125815L, 125823L, 125828L, 125834L, 125838L, 125845L, 
125852L, 125864L, 125871L, 125880L, 125889L, 125893L, 125896L, 
125899L, 125902L, 125904L, 125912L, 125920L, 125931L, 125936L, 
125944L, 125952L, 125961L, 125963L, 125969L, 125978L, 125984L, 
125991L, 126002L, 126009L, 126018L, 126025L, 126028L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried `aes(x=X, y=Y, color=starttime_ms)` with ggplot? That's a lot of points. I'm not sure the human eye is that sensitive to color changes to make sense of that. You could try with different color scales like `scale_color_viridis_c()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = starttime_ms)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("red", "gold", "forestgreen"), name = "time")
```

[image]

An alternative that might help keep track of the motion better would be to use `geom_segment`:

```r
df$X2 <- dplyr::lag(df$X)
df$Y2 <- dplyr::lag(df$Y)

ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = starttime_ms)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = X2, yend = Y2), size = 1) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("red", "gold", "forestgreen"), name = "time")
```

[image]